# Корзина WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте! У меня проблема с wordpress. Сделал мультиязычный интернет-магазин. Под конец обнаружил проблему с корзиной. Когда я с русской версии сайта перехожу в корзину то нормально, закидывает в русскую корзину. Но когда захожу с агнлийской версии в корзину то закидывает все время в русскую.(аглийская версия страницы корзины сделана, по ссылке перехожу - работает) Первый раз использовал для мультиязычия плагин Polylang, вот тогда и вылезла эта проблема, то кидает все время в русскую корзину, то в английскую (потом мне сказали что он с Woocommerce не особо дружит). Теперь использую WPML, к моему недоумению вылез тот же баг. Помогите чем сможете. Куда смотреть, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Для полного перевода WooCommerce через WPML нужен плагин WooCommerce Multilingual. После его установки указанные проблемы исчезают.